# Read Bloqueante em C

Tags: c, socket

Estou a tentar fazer um servidor em C. Após receber a conexão do cliente o objectivo é ficar à espera de informação do cliente no socket, para isso utilizo o seguinte código.

```
/*Read Messages*/
        close(fd);
        nread = read(fd, msg, BUFFERSIZE-1);
        close(fd);
        msg[nread] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", msg);
```

A função `close(fd)` vai fechar/limpar o socket antes de fazer a leitura.
Mas o problema acontece na leitura, `read()`. A minha duvida é se os `close(fd)` estão colocados correctamente e se isso é a consequência do `read` ler lixo.

Comment: Bom, esse close não deveria nem estar aí também. Seria bom você partir de um código que já funciona, e adaptar para o seu uso gradativamente. Em todo o caso, editei minha resposta para tentar ser mais abrangente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o servidor aceita um cliente, ele cria um processo ou thread que fica encarregue de trabalhar com esse cliente. Antes de entregar trabalho a esse processo, fechamos o `fd` do cliente. Por exemplo:

```
while (1) {
     client = accept(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_addr_size);
     if (client > 0) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(fd);
            process_client(client);
            exit(0);
        }
    close(client);
    }
}
```

A função `process_client` irá ser o `worker` desse processo. Ou seja a função está encarregue de ficar à espera de informação no socket.

```
void process_client(int client_fd)
{
    int nread = 0;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    nread = read(client_fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE-1);
    buffer[nread] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);
    fflush(stdout);
    close(client_fd);
}
```

Se o objectivo for estar sempre a espera de informação no socket vinda do cliente basta colocar toda a função num ciclo `While(1)`

Answer (score 4):

> Essa afirmação nem sempre é verdadeira: *"Como toda a gente sabe o read de um socket é bloqueante, ou seja, fica sempre à espera de informação no socket."*

Um socket pode ser ou não "bloqueante", depende meramente de setar esta propriedade no stream.

O que pode estar acontecendo, no seu caso, é o read estar bloqueando, mas ao receber dados novos, ele normalmente retorna o valor e sai do estado de bloqueio (isso é esperado).

Experimente utilizar algo como o código a seguir para avaliar o que está passando pelo seu stream, para ver se os dados corretos estão chegando, e se o que você está recebendo são dados de controle e/ou caracteres especiais (lembre-se de por algum critério no código para sair do loop infinito, se não tiver como dar break no código ;) ).

```
while ((numread = read(sock_fd, &buff, 1)) > 0) {
   write(out_fd, &buff, 1);
}
```

Eis aqui uma função que serve para configurar o comportamento do bloqueio tanto em linux quanto windows:

```
#import <fcntl.h>

/** Retorna true se funcionou, ou false se houve algum erro
  * fd é o file descriptor em que for aplicar o parâmetro
  * blocking é true ou false, definindo se o socket vai ser "bloqueante" ou não
  */
bool SetSocketBlockingEnabled(int fd, bool blocking)
{
   if (fd < 0) return false;

#ifdef WIN32
   unsigned long mode = blocking ? 0 : 1;
   return (ioctlsocket(fd, FIONBIO, &mode) == 0) ? true : false;
#else
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
   if (flags < 0) return false;
   flags = blocking ? (flags&~O_NONBLOCK) : (flags|O_NONBLOCK);
   return (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) == 0) ? true : false;
#endif
}
```

<sub>Código original [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549344)</sub>

Comment: Estou a ser enganado na universidade então, mas de qualquer das formas essa é uma das soluções para evitar o lixo no socket?

Comment: Tente editar a pergunta para refletir o que você precisa exatamente, e dê mais detalhes sobre o problema do lixo, para que eu ou alguém possa te ajudar melhor. Pode até ter a ver com o lixo o fato da sua função estar saindo onde deveria bloquear. Talvez se você puder por o código mais completo, facilite. De qualquer forma, a função serve para você ter certeza do estado do stream.